# Customizing Byobu

Tags: bash, scripts, byobu

I'm trying to configure Byobu to show the computers external IP-adress by using this little script in .byobu/bin. The script is called 10_ipadress and contains these lines:

```
#!/bin/sh
wget -qO- http://ipecho.net/plain ; echo
```

The script it self works from the commandline, so it has the right permissions and is execuable. But it does not show up on the panel. So I guess there is something wrong with the script itself, but I can't figure out what exactly.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thank you, Pilot6

Answer (score 1):

Byubo already has this covered in the settings file.

[From the manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man1/byobu.1.html):

> **ip_address4** - the IPv4 address of the system in dotted decimal form; displayed in the upper bar on the far right in bold black text on a grey background; you can show your external ip address by setting 'IP_EXTERNAL=1' in $BYOBU_CONFIG_DIR/statusrc

So you can already do what you want by editing `statusrc` and adding `IP_EXTERNAL=1`. If you want it to show the ipv6 address also add `IPV6=1`.

Comment: Again a RT*M? :)